# Sufficient Statistic for $f(x,\theta)=\dfrac{2}{\theta^{2}} (\theta-x) \cdot 1_{(0,\theta)}(x), \;\forall \theta \in (0,\theta) $

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Let $X_{1},\ldots, X_{n}$ be random variables independent and identically distributed; show that the following density function is in the exponential family and find the sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

$$ f(x, \theta)=f(x,\theta)=\dfrac{2}{\theta^{2}} (\theta-x) \cdot 1_{(0,\theta)}(x), \;\forall x \in (0,\theta) $$

**My attempt is**

$f(x, \theta)=e^{\ln(\theta-x)+\ln(2/\theta^{2})}\cdot 1_{(0,\theta)}(x)$.

My question is: can I consider $T(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(\theta-x_{1})$ a sufficient statistic for $\theta?$ If the sufficient statistic cannot depend on the parameter, does this density function not have a sufficient statistic?
How to reduce this expression so that the statistic found does not depend on $\theta$?

Comment: You need to factorize the likelihood to correspond with that of an exponential family. Note that the sufficient statistic should only be a function of the data (not $\theta)$ so your proposal is wrong.

Comment: This is also clearly not an exponential family since the support depends on the parameter

Comment: If I can not express it like a exponential family , then does not have a sufficient statistics?

Comment: No; all models have a sufficient statistic. Although that sufficient statistic might be the trivial $T(\mathbf{X}) = \mathbf{X}$ all the data

Comment: But, I can not reduce more to find $T(X)=X$ that does not depend of $\theta$

Comment: That is indeed the case

Comment: You might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Uniform_distribution for hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your sufficient statistic must be a [statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic) ---i.e., it is a function of the data but it *cannot* depend on $\theta$.  You figure out the sufficient statistic by first writing out the likelihood function for a full data vector and stripping it down to the parts that depend on the parameter:

$$\begin{align}
L_\mathbf{x}(\theta) 
&= \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i | \theta) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2}{\theta^2} (\theta - x_i) \mathbb{I}(0 \leqslant x_i \leqslant \theta) \\[6pt]
&= 2^n \theta^{-2n} \Bigg( \prod_{i=1}^n (\theta - x_i) \Bigg) \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_{(1)} \geqslant 0) \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_{(n)} \leqslant \theta) \\[6pt]
&= 2^n \theta^{-2n} \Bigg( \prod_{i=1}^n (\theta - x_{(i)}) \Bigg) \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_{(1)} \geqslant 0) \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_{(n)} \leqslant \theta) \\[6pt]
&\overset{\theta}{\propto} \theta^{-2n} \exp \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n \ln (\theta - x_{(i)}) \Bigg) \cdot \mathbb{I}(x_{(n)} \leqslant \theta). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

The [Fisher-Neyman factorisation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem) says that a statistic $\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x})$ (which might be a scalar or a vector) is sufficient if there is a function $g$ such that:

$$L_\mathbf{x}(\theta) \overset{\theta}{\propto} g(\mathbf{T}(\mathbf{x}), \theta).$$

For IID data from *any* distribution, the [ordered sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) $\mathbf{x}_\text{ord} = (x_{(1)},...,x_{(n)})$ is always a sufficient statistic.  We can see that these values are sufficient to decompose the likelihood function as required above, so this is just like any other IID case where the ordered sample is sufficient.

Of course, in the present case we would want to go further and find the *minimal sufficient statistic*, so the question then becomes: is there any *reduced* statistic (involving a loss of information compared to the ordered sample) that is still sufficient?  What do you think?  Can you find one and show it is sufficient?  If not, can you prove that any sufficient statistic must be a function of the ordered sample?

Comment: Taking the logarithms is legitimate, but it seems like a step in the wrong direction: expanding the product of the $\theta - x_{(i)}$ will more quickly help readers arrive at an expression for $\mathbf T.$

Comment: @whuber: I only really did this to liken the function to OP's expression of it, just to confirm that the existing reasoning in the question is (partly) on-track.  But yes, the product expression is at least as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look at the likelihood ratio
$$
\text{LR}=\prod_i \frac{(2/\theta^2)(\theta-x_i)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0,\theta)}(x_i)}{(2/\psi^2)(\psi-x_i)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0,\psi)}(x_i)}
$$
defined for $\max_i x_i < \min(\theta, \psi)$. Use that the likelihood ratio is a function of any sufficient statistic. The above can be simplified to
$$
\text{LR}=\frac{\psi^2}{\theta^2}\prod_i \frac{\theta-x_i}{\psi-x_i}.
$$